# Vehicle picture blocked buying online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If you go to each of the websites for buying vehicles, (Warstock, Elitas, Legendary, etc.) Some of the vehicles on each site have a symbol instead of a picture of the vehicle.  For the cars from Los Santos Autos, it was believed that you had to steal them for Simeon first.  However, there are two facts that contradict this:

1. Vehicles blocked with a symbol include vehicles from other sites, vehicles that Simeon doesn't want and you can't bring to him or steal and sell.
2. The Dinka Double T is one of the cars blocked by a symbol.  I have not brought a Double T to Simeon but I was able to buy one from the website and have it delivered.

Does anyone know why certain vehicles have symbols over them?

Comment: I think it's because them vehicles simply don't have pictures for them. For some reason. You can buy all the cars.

Comment: I had the same issue but after the Beach Bum update I now have pictures for all vehicles on all sites. I'm guessing they simply hadn't loaded these pictures for all cars at time of release.